# why some related entities are not serialized to JSON?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In spring-boot I have two entities  :

```
package interv.Entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Intervention implements Serializable {

            @Id @GeneratedValue
            private Long Id;

            private String objet;

            @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
            private Date date;

            @Column(columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT false")
            private boolean valid;



            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="id_Project")
            @JsonBackReference(value="projet-intervention")
            private Project project;


            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
            @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-intervention")
            private AppUser appUser;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name ="Id_AppDevlopper")
            @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-intervention-devlopper")
            private AppUser app ;

}
```

Also Project entity :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Project implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String intitule;
        private String description;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_appUser")
        @JsonBackReference(value="projet-appuser")
        private AppUser appUser;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
        @Fetch(value=FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @JsonManagedReference(value="projet-intervention")
        private Collection<Intervention> interventions = new ArrayList<Intervention>();



        public void addToIntervention(Intervention intervention) { this.interventions.add(intervention);}


 }
```

IN angular5 i'm trying to get page of intervention of a specific user using  a rest controller of spring with this  query :

```
@Query("select i from Intervention i where i.appUser = :userApp")
    public Page<Intervention> interventionsOfClient(@Param("userApp") AppUser userApp  , Pageable pageable);
```

The rest controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="clientsintervention",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Intervention> getClientsIntervention(
            @RequestParam(name="page",defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(name="size",defaultValue = "5") int size,
            @RequestParam(name="id",defaultValue ="0") Long id
    ){

         AppUser appUser = userRepo.getOne(id);

         return interventionRepo.interventionsOfClient(appUser,new PageRequest(page,size));
    }
```

This method return a page of interventions , each intervention contains {id,object,date,valid} and  there is not the object Project that i'm expecting and i want to use in my front end page .

Any idea on how to resolve that ?

Comment: Do you a git repo in which I could look into?

Comment: Spring boot or angular ?

Comment: @lealceldeiro : Ah non i don't :/

Comment: @Antoniossss : im using both , but the problem i face is in angular5 i cant get all the elements of Project using the query in the repository . Console.log(data) sent by spring boot show only id object date and valid

Comment: But its not angular related. No angular code, no angular issues here... no tag ;P

Comment: @Antoniossss just shame on me , i'll edit it again

Comment: For starters: Use http interceptor to add auth headers to every request. That looooong http call makes my eyes hurt ;)

Comment: Another: dont build query string on your own. use http params for this

Comment: good remark , i'll change it next , so do you have any idea on why i'm not getting the project object ?

Comment: And as I say-its not angular related. You are asking why some related entities are not serialized to JSON. That s the question.

Comment: What willl happen if you remove  @JsonBackReference(value="projet-appuser") from project?

Comment: Yes exactly , i think there is a problem with the entity appUser .

Comment: a lot of problem , i used JsonBackReference becaus before adding it i was fascing error about infinit loop between appUser and project

Comment: Please trim your question....

Comment: Remove all angular related stuff as it is not related to your problem. leave controler and entitiies and paste actual rest response marking what is expected response .

Comment: Try to switch `ManagerReference` with `BackReference` for project field in intervention and in project accordinly. In general it should work as it is

Comment: My bet is that if you try to serialize project with with interventions it will be as expected. Managed reference should be on "parent' entity. You got the other way around

Comment: switching between ManagerReference with BackReference gives errors , serialize project with interventions ? project and intervention are already serialized

Comment: You complain about not serializing some relations, and now they are serialized? So problem solved?

Comment: Oh wait a minute , this is not what i mean , it's my mistake , i thought you are talking about serializing class Project and intervention , Sorry . {extends serializable}

Comment: No, I said try to return Project as response (insteed of intervention)- my bet is that it will contain interventions. You want the other way around. However this may not work that way due to paren-child relation. Im not sure, didnt test that

Comment: So , what should i do now ? i'm not able anymore to understand what's happening .

Comment: So this is not possible ?

Comment: Use `@JsonIdentityInfo` as for some reason `@JsonBackReference` is not working for me either.